# Deterministic Multi-tape Turing Machine construction

Tags: turing-machines, complexity-classes

I'm trying to construct a deterministic multi-tape turing machine for the following language in order to show that $L$ is in $DTIME(n)$:

$$L = \{ www \mid w \in \{a,b\}^+ \}$$

I'm not sure how to get started. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could copy the input to 3 tapes, then move the heads on tapes 2 and 3 until they point to the same substring and on tape 3, the end of substring matches the end of string.

The exact steps could be..

> 1. copy input
>  2. erase first symbol on tape two and first two symbols on tape three
>  3. go forward on all tapes until...
>  4. if one of the symbols is different than on other tapes, go back to the start of each tape and return to step 2
>  5. if tape three reaches end of input, you are done

Comment: "move the heads on tapes 2 and 3 until they point ..." That is hard given the fact these positions are not marked in the input.

Comment: @HendrikJan, you do string comparisons as you go. It's not that hard.

Comment: But string comparisons is much harder than the copying part in your hint, in my view. I would compute the position by dividing into 3, which is a nice trick when having two tapes.